# Can anyone give me an easy explanation about "self=super init"?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I still don't understand self=super init; ,although I read many many books and googles.
I know that it is used for checking the current object equals to the return object from the parent class etc.
However, I can not accept that is the answer. Can someone give me an easy but solid acceptable answer?
Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The quick answer is that you are telling the super class of your class to initialise the object. Because you are inheriting from that super class, then you can perform other initialisation tasks specific to your implementation, but first you have to make sure the basics of initialisation are performed (which is handled by the base class NSObject). Each class that extends (inherits) from another class has to make sure their super class has been initialised before they can do their initialisation.

A very quickly made up (and therefore probably quite poor) analogue - before you could be created, your parents had to be created (the super class) and they had to have their parents created first (their super class)

I suggest you search for object oriented programming basics to learn about this sort of thing.

Comment: +2 for the answer, -1 for the visual of my parents :)

Answer (score 0):

Your mention of "checking" makes me think that you are seeing `=` as a comparison operation. It's not. It's an assignment. Sometimes the assignment appears within an `if` condition. That's taking advantage of the fact that assignment expressions have a value -- the value that was assigned. So, `if (self = [super init])` combines "call super's `-init` method", "assign the result to `self`", **and** "check if we got non-nil from super's `-init`" (that is, that super didn't fail to initialize).

Because this combined assignment-and-test can be confusing and error-prone, Apple now recommends separating the assignment out from the check for failure:

```
self = [super init];
if (self)
    // ... continue initializing ...
```

Comment: In C, any non-zero value evaluates to true for a boolean test.  The NULL pointer and `nil` convert to zero and thus false for a boolean test.

Answer (score -1):

NSObject is root class.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html 
You can find an `init` method there. That `init` method within `NSObject` class is the initializer for every object in Objective-C. `super` simply returns super class of a object.

If `Class B` was inherited from `Class A`, `Class A` will be super class of `Class B`. Again another class `Class C` which was inherited from `Class B`, the super class of `Class C` will be `Class B`. So on.

When you call `[super init];` from a class, it simply call `init` method of its super class, which in turn call `init` method of its super class and so on. At last it will reach root object NSObject, and call the real `init` method. At that point the iOS will allocate memory for your object and necessary data structures for your object. Read documentation about each method and property in NSObject class.

If you created a class `MyView` which is subclass of `UIView`, your class hierarchy will be.

```
     NSObject

UIAppearanceContainer

   UIAppearance

     NSCoding

      UIView

      MyView
```

So when you call `init` method in your class 'MyView', it will call

init method of UIView

UIView will call init method of NSCoding

NSCoding will call init method of UIAppearance

UIAppearance will call init method of UIAppearanceContainer

UIAppearanceContainer will call init method of NSObject.

Comment: In second step of the above example, will UIView call init method of NSCoding automatically or we need to write another self =super init in the UIView?

Comment: inside UIView there is there a call self=[super init] as same as in every method

Comment: I would like to know what wrong with this answer. Please enter your comment(to whom down voted this answer :) ).